Take the elements of lists in 2 columns, find all the combination pairs between the columns, and then form 2 columns that consist of those pairs
I have a dataframe (table) as below:



color
cars




red, blue, green
BMW, Mercedes


blue, yellow
Porsche, Jeep, Volvo



combination pairs table:
I want to form a new dataframe (table) that consists of the combination pairs between the 2 columns



color
cars




red
BMW


red
Mercedes


blue
BMW


blue
Mercedes


green
BMW


green
Mercedes


blue
Porsche


blue
Jeep


blue
Volvo


yellow
Porsche


yellow
Jeep


yellow
Volvo



Something like this can be done with nested for loops, but I am not sure how to do this in Pandas and then create the combination pairs table above.
list_1 = ["red", "blue", "green"]
list_2 = ['bmw', ' mercedes']

output = []
for i in list_2:
    for j in list_1:
        output.append([j, i])
print(*output, sep=', ')

['red', 'bmw'], ['blue', 'bmw'], ['green', 'bmw'], ['red', ' mercedes'], ['blue', ' mercedes'], ['green', ' mercedes']


Does this answer your question? cartesian product in pandas

Assuming this dataframe as input:
data = {
    "color": ["red, blue, green", "blue, yellow"],
    "cars": ["BMW, Mercedes", "Porsche, Jeep, Volvo"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

              color                  cars
0  red, blue, green         BMW, Mercedes
1      blue, yellow  Porsche, Jeep, Volvo

You can use this approach:
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(", ")
    df = df.explode(col)

    color      cars
0     red       BMW
0     red  Mercedes
0    blue       BMW
0    blue  Mercedes
0   green       BMW
0   green  Mercedes
1    blue   Porsche
1    blue      Jeep
1    blue     Volvo
1  yellow   Porsche
1  yellow      Jeep
1  yellow     Volvo


This approach works! Thank-you very much for the help!

You could leverage the python itertools module  [link]https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
trivial example:
cat glucosebat.py 
from itertools import product

g1=["red", "blue", "green"]
g2=['BMW', 'Mercedes']
g3=['blue', 'yellow']
g4=['Porsche','Jeep','Volvo']

cp=list(product(g1,g2)) + list(product(g3,g4))  # merge results

print( 'color\tcars')
for k in cp:
    print(k)

python3 glucosebat.py
color   cars
('red', 'BMW')
('red', 'Mercedes')
('blue', 'BMW')
('blue', 'Mercedes')
('green', 'BMW')
('green', 'Mercedes')
('blue', 'Porsche')
('blue', 'Jeep')
('blue', 'Volvo')
('yellow', 'Porsche')
('yellow', 'Jeep')
('yellow', 'Volvo')

# process further as needed ...

hope this is of help.

That's a very interesting approach and it works. Thanks!
